# Elasticsearch 8.6.2 Failed to parse mapping: analyzer has not been configured in mappings

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to use an Elasticsearch python client to ingest a mapping to Elasticsearch with the code below.

```
es_mappings = {
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 5,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "id": {"type": "integer"},
        "name": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "my_analyzer"},
        "desc": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "my_analyzer"},
        "datetime_create": {"type": "date"},
        "site_name": {"type": "text"}
    }
}

response = es.indices.create(index="<INDEX_NAME>", mappings=es_mappings, ignore=400)
```

And got the error

```
ObjectApiResponse({'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'Failed to parse mapping: analyzer [my_analyzer] has not been configured in mappings'}], 'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'Failed to parse mapping: analyzer [my_analyzer] has not been configured in mappings', 'caused_by': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'analyzer [my_analyzer] has not been configured in mappings'}}, 'status': 400})
```

I am also trying to use put_mapping() and put_settings(), but it doesn't work.
How to solve this error? Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
I tried separating the mapping and settings and using

```
 response = es.indices.create(index="<INDEX_NAME>", mappings=es_mappings, settings=es_settings, ignore=400)
```

And the error message is `'unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.tokenizer.my_tokenizer.max_gram] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings'`

**SOLVED**
I solve the above error by removing the params "settings" at the top of the JSON and it works!

Answer (score 1):

The settings must be sent in its own parameter not as part of the mappings:

```
es_mappings = { ... }
es_settings = { ... }


response = es.indices.create(index="<INDEX_NAME>", mappings=es_mappings, settings=es_settings, ...)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. 
I try it and get this error message.

`{'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.tokenizer.my_tokenizer.max_gram] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings'}`

Comment: Add an update to your question to show exactly what you're sending now

Comment: This error has been solved. I solved it by removing the params: "settings" at the top of the es_settings and it works!

Comment: Yes, that key needed to be removed indeed. Glad you figured it out!